# CSS code to show tags in a rounded box breaks once uploaded to server

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have CSS code to show tags and on my `localhost` (Node.Js app) everything looks ok, but once I upload it on the server, a strange line appears, also both versions use the same git repository.

Do you know what the problem could be?

This is the HTML code

```
<ul class="tags">
<li><a href="#">tag 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">tag 2</a></li>
<div class="tagsend"></div>
</ul>
```

and CSS

```
.tags{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.tags li, .tags a{
    float:right;
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
}

.tagsend {
    clear:both;
}

.tags a{
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:0 10px 0 12px;
    background:#0089e0;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
}

.tags a:before{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-12px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent #0089e0 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px 12px 12px 0;
}

.tags a:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    width:4px;
    height:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
    box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px #004977;
}

.tags a.notfound{
    background: #666666;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
.tags a.notfound:before{
    border-color:transparent #666666 transparent transparent;
}

.tags a:hover{
    background:#666;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.tags a:hover:before{
    border-color:transparent #555 transparent transparent;
}
```

[image: broken css]

[image: good css]

Comment: Seems OK here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g77L73f2/

Comment: It would help to know on what browser / OS / version combinations this works locally and on which it doesn't. Also, in order to help you properly, you may need to show the "broken" example as well. Is it available online?

Comment: @garcia I'm using Mac on the local and it's Linux on the server.

Comment: The server OS is not as important. I was referring to the OS of the client, but more importantly the Internet Browser which you are using to test the page (ie: Chrome, Firefox, IE...) knowing whether this affects all browsers or just some is a key piece of information.

Comment: Also, it seems that the style differences are numerous, not just the extra line, but the boxes appear of smaller size, the rounded dot turns into a square, and the font size is smaller. This seems to point at conflicting CSS, so my guess is that you have CSS on the server which you don't have locally, and this is what is causing the discrepancy.

Comment: Chrome and you can login using test/test on http://infranodus.com and just click some nodes to see how it looks. Safari seems to be fine.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot insert a DIV outside of an LI in a list.

Comment: Error on my side (Firefox latest build), shows only when i try to zoom in. Not always though, is some % of zooming for example 150%, etc. I know this isnt the solution you are looking for, it might help to find the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual artifacts are quite possibly related to having Chrome zoomed out at a level other than 100% (thanks to @ArberBraja for the hint and for actually finding this out). I don't experience the issue at all with the default 100% zoom level in Chrome, but I do when I zoom out to 90%:

[image: screenshot]

If this is still an issue (ie: you need to support "pixel perfect" rendering at all zoom levels), you would need to rework the way that you add the tag's angled tip to be a little less clever:

```
.tags a:before{
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-12px; // This is the problem
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent #0089e0 transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:12px 12px 12px 0;
}
```

Since you are offsetting the border by 12 pixels to the left, this number is being scaled down by Chrome to values that produce a less than pixel perfect result. You may need to use a solid background image for the whole tag in order to support all zoom levels properly.

Comment: Thank you! It was related to the zooming of the browser and I will try your suggestion to change CSS code.